# Intermittent black box when writing a post on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

When entering a Q&A at the same time (i.e. "Answer your own question" is checked), if you click the preview box for the answer, a black box is displayed  instead of your answer.

I have tested on HTC One V, Android 4.0.3, SE app v0.1.31.

Screenshot

[image: black box on error message][image: black box on post body]

[image: nothing wrong][image: black box on error message again]

Comment: There is no "answer your own question". In the Android app, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yes There is. I have downloaded application just few moment before and "Add an Answer" button provided. I think you need to install newer version of app.

Comment: That's possible. I've got 0.1.31, what version do you have?

Comment: I have 0.1.31 as well and do not see an "Answer your own question" option either. I haven't tried asking a question from the app though. I'm not exactly sure what it does after clicking Submit but I would assume it just posts the question (that is unless it offers additional options then).

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're using the official app.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi is Michael Clark, Stack Exchange OWNER is guiding us correctly ? as i'm downloading Stack Exchange App from the urls provided here in discussion https://plus.google.com/u/1/communities/116770445014869505908

Comment: From the screenshots it looks like you *are* running on the official application, you're just a bit confused about some things which is OK. The screenshots look like an issue is happening with your phone not supporting hardware acceleration, but telling us that it does support it. Are you running a custom ROM or something? Do you have "Force GPU Acceleration" checked in the developer settings of your phone?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi :-= Thanks. My device don't have "Force GPU Acceleration" or external RAM. Also, it is also reproducible on Samsung 4.0.3 devices.

Comment: Is this still an issue @swapnil - we have made a lot of changes around rendering.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas -  I tried to luanch application today. It asked me to upgrade. But, unfortunately I was redirected to 404. nothing was found. Please provide me a link so I could download latest .apk

Comment: Make sure you are signed in to Google play with the same account you received the invite.